# How make the output in Azure DataStudio more readable?

Tags: azure-data-studio

The output are has a bad readable. Is it possible to increase the front size, the front size is way do small and not readable? I did already checked the settings but i did not find anything.

[image]

I did already checked the settings but i did not find anything. I do not understand why its not easy to do.

Comment: Do you mean increase the *font* size? Here are multiple options for the font in the application; just type "font" in the settings. Or do you want *everything" bigger? Try `Ctrl`+`+`?

Comment: Only the the font size and front style on the output area. Other should stay the same.

Comment: What is the "front"? You've said it multiple times now, so I assume you do actually meant "front" and not *font*, but I have no idea what you mean by it. What is the "front" of ADS (and what is the back)?

Comment: I mean font. I want to change the font size and style

Comment: So what is *actually* stopping you..?

Comment: how to do it in datastudio?

Comment: What's stopping you is how to do it? That doesn't make sense. What's with changing the settings? Why are you unable to change them?

Comment: There are not settings for this issue

Answer (score 1):

There are *multiple* settings for fonts in Azure Data Studio. Open the Settings in ADS, File->Preferences->Settings/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, then in the Search bar at the top type "font".

If you want to change the font style where you type code then you want the setting "**Editor: Font Family**" and for the size "**Editor: Font Size**". There's also a setting for the terminal and results grid with similar names (Just replace **Editor** with **Terminal > Intergrated**/**Results Grid**). Some addons also give options (for example the Markdown addon I have installed).

If you want to make the entire environment larger then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, and conversely <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will make everything smaller.

As with anything, you can edit all these settings, and more, in the JSON editor for the settings too; accessible by clicking the cog in the upper right when in the Settings menu.